# Eclipse hangs while starting, shows message as "Initializing Spring Tooling"

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, eclipse-oxygen

Eclipse (Oxygen) hangs while starting/restarting, shows message as **Initializing Spring Tooling** at right bottom corner as below and always be in **Not Responding** state.

Killed the process multiple times by **Task Manager** to exit and restarted several times but doesn't help.

Can please someone help to fix this ?

[image]

Comment: Before asking, please make sure your used software is up to date. Eclipse Oxygen is more than four years and 14 releases behind. There is a separate Stack Exchange for [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @howlger Eclipse which used is up to date. This issue looks like more of workspace issue.

Comment: The screenshot shows an outdated Eclipse. The current Eclipse version is 2021-09 (4.21). Maybe also your STS is outdated or does not work with the outdated Eclipse version you using.

Comment: Using this eclipse since months and it was working fine. Facing this issue from last two days in current workspace. Its working fine with new workspace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Below steps will resolve the issue:**

1. Terminate Eclipse IDE with Task Manager and delete below folder:

   `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history`
2. There will be folder `.metadata` in your Eclispe workspace. Just delete the `.log` files in it.
3. Move to path where `eclipse.exe` is available. Then from Command Prompt just type

   `eclipse.exe -clean`

Comment: Thank you for share this information. This is useful too for Spring Tool Suite.